# Html sitemap issue

Tags: magento2, sitemaps

Facing some issues with `html sitemap`.

I created a `xml Sitemap`from bacakend but when I load this link :

> http://localhost/PG2/catalog/seo_sitemap/product/

I have this error:

> The page you requested was not found
>
> We have a fine guess why
>
> - If you typed the URL directly, please make sure the spelling is correct.
> - If you clicked on a link to get here, the link is outdated.
>
> What can you do?
>
> - Have no fear, help is near! There are many ways you can get back on track with Magento Store.
> - Go back to the previous page.
> - Use the search bar at the top of the page to search for your products.
> - Follow these links to get you back on track! Store Home | My Account